Is it possible to set a nickname for Android device?
Is it possible to set a nickname for Android device? (So, in notification messages Android displays this nickname instead of "your phone"?)
Example:

now: "your phone is charged"
wanted: "Lulu is charged"


Without a rooted device, unlikely. With a rooted device, possibly, depending on where that variable is pulled from
